# How to Select Div Element except two with :not jquery

Tags: jquery

I have code something like this

```
<div id="abc"></div>
<div id="abc2"></div>
    <div id="abc3"></div>
<div id="abc4"></div>
    <div id="abc5"></div>
```

I want to select all div except div with id abc4 & abc using :not

My attempt:

```
$('div :not("#abc","#abc4")').hover(function(){...})
```

Comment: what did you try?  The docs for both `:not` selector and `not()` method are quite straightforward. At least provide an attempt at coding it

Comment: Check the first demo - http://api.jquery.com/not/ and answer to your question - ​$('div').not('#abc, #abc4').css('border', '1px solid #f00');​

Comment: i tried here's my code 
i tried but won't work
$('div :not("#abc","#abc4")').hover(function(){...})

Comment: is simply 2 syntax errors ( space before "not" and extra quotes). In future provide the code right away, saves everyone time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the difference for yourself -

```
​$('div:not("#abc, #abc4")').css('border', '1px solid #f00'); // I suggest​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('div:not("#abc", "#abc4")').hover(function(){...}) // Yours
```

you are adding extra double quotes which is not necessary

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yKhtK/)

Comment: also the removed space in selector is important

Comment: +0, I upvoted the _first_ answer, which was _right_ (just missing one tiny little edit).  You essentially copied his answer.

Comment: @mmmshuddup this is a very basic of jquery I had already posted the answer in comment before the other guy answers.... :) And I posted my answer to show the OP quote mistake

Comment: @mmmshuddup you added this comment without reading - i tried here's my code i tried but won't work $('div :not("#abc","#abc4")').hover(function(){...})